# Free C/C++ IDE & compiler to create command line Mysql access program

Tags: gratis, c++, ide, c, mysql

I just need to code a short command line program to run a `SELECT` and convert the result to CSV, so am open to any free IDE/Compiler solution for Windows 10.

I tried MS Visual Studio and the [official Mysql connector](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/), but from the menu Tools/Connect to database, I only see options for MS & Oracle, nothing for MySql.

So, I guess I am looking for something else?

---

[Update] Look, guys, I do appreciate that you are trying to help, but please, no more answers with stored procedures or the like.

I ***must*** be able to connect to a MySql database and execute arbitrary commands (plus a whole lot more non-Mysql functionality) from C++.

Please also note, that I do not want to drive Mysql through the c `shell()`, `popen()` or similar  function, as if from the command line. I need to use a database connector from C++.

Can we please stick with recommending an IDE which will make that easy? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try these instruction I found at mysql website regarding visual studio?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-making-a-connection.html

Comment: Yes, thanks (+1). I also tried the VS instructions at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/mysql/  Still no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) has a [MySQL connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). [Here is an explanation](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mysql-connector-for-java-how-to-install-in-eclipse-and-tomcat/) on how to install it in Eclipse.

Eclipse also supports C/C++ software development - with the [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) (C/C++ Development Toolkit), and is one of the most prominent free software IDEs. It's not perfect - and certainly not as polished for C/C++ use as it is for Java - but I use it extensively. You can absolutely use it to write command-line applications, specifically ones which send queries to DBMSes and write CSV output.

The only unknown is whether the MySQL connector for Eclipse can interact, or even coexist, with CDT. That you'll have to check for yourself since I don't use MySQL nor its connector with Eclipse.

I will add, though, that even without the connector component, you should still not have a problem writing your program using Eclipse as an IDE.

Comment: Alas, the referenced article is for Java, and not for C/C++. This should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Mawg: See my edit (the last paragraph). If you're 100% sure the connector can't be somehow accessed when doing C/C++ development, I'll remove that part of the answer entirely.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a weekend project, and I have literally no free time midweek (5 hours total commute). I will get back to it on Saturday. Feel free to expand on your last sentence :-) even if it is just a URL of some code that I can copy (+1)

Comment: Half a year has passed.

Comment: And the project is long abandoned :-(

Comment: @Mawg: Then, please consider deleting your question, because I think it's not well-enough focused. (And it doesn't look like you're going to accept answers or try them out.)

Comment: I don't see how I can focus it any more? Can you advise me, please? I ought to have said that the project is shelved, rather than abandoned, as there is a slim chance that it might go ahead in future, so I will leave the question open. But, as I can't see how to focus the question better, I would eb grateful for your advice.

Comment: @Mawg: There is no such thing as an IDE for writing a specific kind of program with a specific function. You can ask for: 1. A C/C++ IDE for command-line programs. 2. A command-line MySQL access program. 3. A C/C++ library or other software framework for accessing MySQL DBMSes in your applicaiton. Choose one.

Comment: I was hoping for as IDE with built in support, maybe a wizard, or menu option, to generate code to access the d/b. Know you of such a beast?

Comment: @Mawg: The "built in support" is support for writing software. In general. Period. You're asking for an IDE specific to the application you want to write. There can be no such thing.

Comment: Such an IDE Would not be specific to my app, as it can also be used to develop any number of other apps. I am asking only for an IDE with a given features, viz. a wizard for d/c connection code generation.

Comment: @Mawg: The given feature will be specific to your app and it is unlikely to ever exist.

Comment: Code to access a MySql database will be specific to may app??!!  Surely others might want to do that? That's all that I ask - a wizard to generate what has always been a pain ever time I have to use a new language.

Comment: @Mawg: That's "all" you ask? You're living in a fantasy world my friend. There are no such wizards. Certainly not part of IDEs.

Comment: Your answer gives a perfectly acceptable solution for Java. Were it for C or C++, I would have accepted it. Therefore, I consider my question not to be unreasonable.  I find your statement that I am "living in a fantasy world" to be bordering on offensive, so let us not continue this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    orderNumber, status, orderDate, requiredDate, comments
FROM
    orders
WHERE
    status = 'Cancelled' 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/tmp/cancelled_orders.csv' 
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TERMINATED BY ';' 
ESCAPED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

Done, no IDE, no compiling.

Command line save above into blah.txt

The 2 p's together are intentional so you can enter the password from the command line also.

mysql -u root -ppassword databaseName

Comment: A very nice try! But, alas, it must be C/C++ and we will release only a single executable

Answer (score 0):

How about built-in stored procedure:

http://blog.secaserver.com/2014/10/mysql-export-table-split-csv-stored-procedure/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039324/stored-procedure-that-exports-data-into-csv-files-only-exports-to-one-file

Ripped from above stack overflow:

```
DECLARE 
   @StartDT DATE, 
   @TableName NVARCHAR(50), 
   @FileLocation VARCHAR(255);

SET @TableName = N'ViewAccountDetail';

SELECT @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', MIN(dos)), '19000101')
   FROM dbo.accn_demographics;

   PRINT @StartDT;
-- ^^^^^ debugging 101 - what month do we think we're starting at?

WHILE @StartDT < '20110901'
BEGIN
    SET @FileLocation = 'C:\test\' + @TableName
      + CONVERT(CHAR(10), @StartDT, 120) + '.csv';

      PRINT @FileLocation;
    --^^^^^ again, debugging 101 - what does the filename currently look like?

    --EXEC BCP_Text_File @TableName, @FileLocation    
    SET @StartDT = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @StartDT);
END
```

No compiling,no IDE, and now with no external files per user request.

Comment: And, how, exactly, am I to invoke that from C++?